# WPF controls visibility dont work

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple switch clause which should show/hide some controls and call a method. Very simple.
Problem is that nothing happens. I'm a web developer and new to WPF. That's why I can't understand why the following doesn't work:

```
switch (_state)
{
    case "ask":
        LabelAsk.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; //not working
        LabelSync.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden; //not working
        ButtonYes.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; //not working
        ButtonNo.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; //not working
        break;
    case "sync":
        LabelAsk.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden; //not working
        LabelSync.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; //not working
        ButtonYes.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden; //not working
        ButtonNo.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden; //not working
        ScanFolders();
        this.Close();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Works for me ... (hiding a grid) ... you sure you're hitting the switch cases?

Comment: Are you sure the program has run this code?

Comment: Don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Create a Proper ViewModel and/or use DataTemplates for this.

Comment: @HighCore your first coment to almost every question is always the same. "dont manipulate ui in procedural code, use xaml, use viewmodels" hahaha :) :)

Comment: @devhedgehog yes, you're an expert developer and you really know what you're doing, but most people out there come to WPF/XAML and try to use it with a winforms mentality, and they fail miserably and create horrendous impossible to maintain or scale monstrosities, that's why I'm always trying to push MVVM here.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your reply.
1. Yes the switch cases are hit because the ScanFolders() method does what it should.
2. @HighCore, you are probably right in what you wrote in your comments. WPF is a paradigm change compared to win forms and web. Can you give an example of how this should be implemented correctly in XAML?

Comment: @HighCore It wasnt mean to be critic, I am just saying I saw your posting the same comments word by word over and over again. I actually like it. So its all fine. :) :)

Comment: @HighCore, funny how others think the same about you.. lol